# Class member of an undeclared class

Tags: c++

How to make this bit of code work, if these two classes are declared in the same ".h" file? How to make it work if they are in the separate ones?

Simple question, but googling didn't help me.

```
class Container
{
    Piece p;
public:
    Container() :p(this) {};
};

class Piece
{
    Container* cont;
public:
    Piece(Container * c) :cont(c) {};
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declare `Container` and then define it later on:

```
class Container;

class Piece
{
    Container* cont;
public:
    Piece(Container * c) :cont(c) {};
};

class Container
{
    Piece p;
public:
    Container() :p(this) {};
};
```

Comment: Why can't I first declare Piece, and after that Container? Is there a way to do it that is not dependent on the order of declaration?

Comment: @shocky2 Because `Piece` holds a pointer to `Container`, pointers are allowed to have an incomplete type, but `Container` has a `Piece` object, objects aren't allowed to be incomplete. An incomplete type being a type that has been forward declared.

Comment: @CisForCookies Just assumed OP meant the other way around.

Comment: Wha if they are in separate files?

Comment: @Shocky2 Files don't change anything, it's still inclusion order.

Comment: @Shocky2 - Then `Container.h` better include `Piece.h`

Comment: @RickAstley Wasn't directed to you :) I meant to explain to OP that what you did is actually declaring Piece first

Answer (score 1):

Forward declaration is what you are looking for.

```
class Container;

class Piece
{
    Container* cont;
public:
    Piece(Container * c) :cont(c) {};
};
class Container
{
    Piece p;
public:
    Container() :p(this) {};
};
```

If you google you would find more information. See the one below.

[When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know the name for it.